# How can i show a different message in cf7 email?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, hidden-field

Good afternoon to all, I'm a newby of this site and programming. I'm working on my first web local site, and I'd like to place a dropdown menu in a Contacf form 7.
So i try to explain which results I'd like.
In this dropdown menu I have 4 choice and id like to receive in the email an additional text for every choice. 
example
drop down menu:
Cats
Dogs
Elephant
Lion

so in the email that I'll receive, if I chose cats, I want also the text "small place"
if I choose dog "medium place"
and so on.
What can I do to have this results?
sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance for every answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CF7 Conditional Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) for that

or

You can insert a hidden input and with some js/jquery you can fill that input with a value based on selected option.

```
$('#selectid').on('change', function() {
  if($('#selectid').val() == "text"){
    $('#inputId').val('insert text');
  }
});
```

and then you can put your hidden input in mail template.

**Update:**

Here is the right code based on your needs:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8csbh5L/)

Comment: You need to give an ID to that select. The same id you add instead of "selectid". The same thing you have to do on that hidden input. You add an ID for the hidden input on CF7 and on the js code you replace "inputId".

Comment: Thanks Paul now i try and i ll let you know:) thankyou bery much:)

Comment: I've made an update. Check the jsfiddle link from the answer. For your situation it's better to use the switch statement.

Comment: Hi Paul, sorri for the delay but i was out for the week end. I tried to put your code in the form, but the last question i hope, how can i put the results in the mail that i'll receive? because in cf mail i can't find the code. Thanks for your patience, but i'm really a newbie:))

Comment: [hidden your-inputName id:inputId]

you put this in Form and then you use [your-inputName] in Mail tab.

Comment: Hi Paul. thanks for your patience, i tryed your code but i'm not able to make it works. so i put chis code in the form part: <div class="content-column one_third">
<select id="selectid">
  <option>Scegli il tuo animale domestico</option>
  <option value="cat">Gatto</option>
  <option value="dog">Cane</option>
<option value="bird">Uccello</option>

</select>
[hidden Selezione-Animale id:inputId]

<label>[email* your-email placeholder "Email*"]</label></div>

Comment: after i put this code on additional part:  $('#selectid').on('change', function() {
  switch($('#selectid option:selected').val()) {
    case 'cat':
      $('#inputId').val('Spazio piccolo richiesto');
      break;
    case 'dog':
      $('#inputId').val('Spazio medio richiesto');
      break;
case 'bird':
      $('#inputId').val('gabbia richiesta');
      break;
  };
});

Comment: and i put this in the email part: Gentile [cognome] [nome] , 

[Selezione-Animale]
what is wrong?

Comment: put the form on jsfiddle / pastebin and I will check

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for all, i put the code in [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/TAUKAI74/8g376jyw/2/) jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Thank very much Paul for your answer, and sorry for my new question but as I told i'm really at beginning.

## selectid (i have to put the name of the dropdown menu?

## inputId i have to put the name of the ddmenu choice?